# Mechanisms of genotype*sex interactions

Tags: genetics, gene-expression, population-genetics, molecular-evolution, quantitative-genetics

I'm looking for suggestions of the mechanistic level at which genotype*sex interactions can occur. These give different phenotypes from the same genotype dependent on the sex they are expressed in. For example, cis-acting sex-specific modifiers can affect gene expression.

What other mechanisms can create a gene*sex interaction?

Comment: I am a little unclear about what you mean by gene*sex interaction

Comment: genotype*sex interaction in determining the phenotype, so a single allele could produce different phenotypes depending on which sex it is in, I am trying to find some known examples of how these sorts of things occur (e.g. known sex-specific gene expression regulation pathways) @WYSIWYG

Comment: Something like [this](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0896627314004826) and [this](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v507/n7491/full/nature13112.html) ?

Comment: Are you talking about [genomic imprinting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genomic_imprinting)?

Comment: So you want to know about the specific molecular mechanisms (e.g. interactions between gene products), and not just examples of gene*sex interactions?

Comment: Yes @fileunderwater